# How to filter boolean attribute with Rails Ransack?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, checkbox, boolean, ransack

In my Rails App I have an episode model. Each episode does have a boolean attribute `cached` which tags the episode as cached.

So `episode.cached?` returns true if the episode is cached.

I want to add a checkbox to my search form that makes it possible to **show only cached episodes in the search result**. I use the ransack gem to build my searches.

This is my current search form:

```
<%= search_form_for @query, url: playlist_management_search_path(channel_playlist: @channel_playlist.id), method: :get, remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :title_or_subtitle_cont, :placeholder => "Verzeichnis durchsuchen", :id => "search-input-field" %>
    <%= f.check_box_tag :cached_true, 1, :checked => @query.cached_true %>
    <%= f.submit "Search", :class => "prefix button" %>
<% end %>
```

With `<%= f.check_box_tag :cached_true, 1, :checked => @query.cached_true %>` I tried to get a checkbox that does what I described above. However it does not work. It says `undefined method 'cached_true' for nil:NilClass`.

So: How can I make a checkbox like **"Only show me episodes with cached = true"?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution myself:

```
<%= f.check_box :cached_true %>
<%= f.label :cached_true %>
```

The `check_box_tag` is only required if you want to loop through a couple of elements and add a check box for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

You use two instance variables: `@query` and `@search`.
I assume `@search` is not set. Try `@query` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I adjusted my post above as it did not solve the problem: Changed the error to `unknown check_box_tag`.